# TableLayoutPanel - Mouse Over Effect

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a TableLayoutPanel on a form (5 columns / 2 rows)  Pictures are presented in row 1 and a description for each picture is presented in row 2.  Is there a way to change the color of the text associated with its picture (row 2) when the user moves the mouse over the picture in (row 1) ?

Comment: If you're showing images in the first row then presumably you have `PictureBox` controls in that row. Handle the `Enter` and `Leave` events of those `PictureBox` controls and modify the `ForeColor` of the corresponding `Label` controls in the second row.

Comment: PictureBox does not like to get the focus.  So use the MouseHover event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course!

If you're using Visual Studio: Click on the Picture/TableLayoutPanel in the designer. Go to Properties, activate the Button Events and in the section Mouse you'll find MouseHover. A double click will open a method in your Windows Forms class. There you can make changes of your text color.

This is possible for all your Controls.

Comment: That's awesome, did not know that existed.  However, I am not sure on how to specify the text in row 2 of the picture that the user has hovered over?

Comment: In the designer class you have the possibility to choose the required control (e.g. lblExample.ForeColor = Color.White).

Comment: Does it work? If yes, I would really appreciate a positive vote and a checkmark! If not - do you have any further questions?